# multiple expressions in SSIS constriant

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

I have two variables: user::runnumber and user::recordcount.

If the `runnumber = 1` OR `recordcount =0`  task A should execute.
Task A is an 'execute package task' that otherwise is functioning fine.
In any other scenario task A should be skipped.

I thought setting the task to disabled using the expression `(@[User::runnumber]==1 ||  @[User::record_count]!=0)` would do the trick but it doesn't.
Any idea on how to tackle this?

```
runnumber = 1 recordcount = 0 --> task A
runnumber = 1 recordcount = 100 --> task A
runnumber = 4 recordcount = 0--> task A
runnumber = 4 recordcount = 4--> skip task A
```

[image: The flow]

[image: current settings]

Comment: Oh, are we using Precedent Constraints (as Mark shows) or are you using an Expression to control the Disable(d) property of the task?

Comment: Both. Previous task should have finished succesfull. (constraint)
expressions controls whether task A is executed. (expression)
How can I upload images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a precedence constraint to control the execution of Task A.  So if your control flow looked something like this:

[image]

Double click the constraint arrow in between the two tasks, set the Evaluation Option to "Expression" and add the following expression:
`@[User::runnumber] == 1 ||  @[User::recordcount] == 0`

EDIT:
Adding configuration of precedence constraint:
[image]

Comment: That's what I thought. But it ain't triggering. It triggers on both conditions individually. But not on the two combined using ||

Comment: oooh...  You said _OR_ in the description.  If you want a logical _AND_ use `&&`.  Let me know if I understood you right.

Comment: I wat it to trigger if runnumber = 0 OR if recordcount =0.
But it won't do that. If I let it run on runnumber ==1, it does what it needs to do. If I set it to recordcount==0, it only runs if recordcount = 0. But if I combine the two using || it does not trigger on either....

Comment: I'm getting confused by what conditions the task should run under.  Would you mind adding a table to your question showing different values and the expected result?

Comment: added table with possible results and desired outcome

Comment: Change the Multiple Constraints section to "Logical AND."  Because you have it set to evaluate both the Expression and Constraint, if the prior task succeeds, this evaluates to true.  If you want to succeed plus evaluate your expression this should be set to AND.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of going about this: Precedence Constraints and the Disabled property.

If there are no paths leaving a Task, then they are equivalent approaches. If there is a "downstream" task that should run regardless of whether the Execute Package Task is fired, then the Disabled property likely makes the most sense. Turning a precedent constraint off disables the entire branch of logic whereas setting Disabled just skips that task for execution.

For the supplied control flow, I'd just have the PC be Success and use the Disabled property.

The property of Disabled is always confusing for me to think about because of the negativity.

Regardless of which approach you take, I would suggest creating boolean variables to track whether the rules of "run execute package task" are met. You can test that independently of the logic for toggling whether the task is run.

I think your core issue might be `@[User::record_count]!=0`  Your business rule is when record_count is zero, then it should be a yes but this is the inversion of that.

For simplicity, I created 3 SSIS Variable, DisableExecutePackageTask of type Boolean and have them defined via Expressions

- EnableEPTRuleRunNumber  `@[User::runnumber]==1`
- EnableEPTRuleRecordCount `@[User::record_count]==0`
- EnableEPT `@[User::EnableEPTRuleRunNumber] || @[User::EnableEPTRuleRecordCount]`

I also defined two variables that I called labels and set the Name property of two Containers to be them so I could see when I ran my package what happened.

-- LabelRunNumber `"RunNumber " + (DT_WSTR, 5) @[User::runnumber] + " rule is " + (DT_WSTR, 10) @[User::EnableEPTRuleRunNumber]`
-- LabelRecordCount `"RecordCount " + (DT_WSTR, 5) @[User::record_count] + " rule is " + (DT_WSTR, 10) @[User::EnableEPTRuleRecordCount]`

Then I would change the value of my variables runnumber and record_count to evaluate the scenarios.

[image: number 1 count 0]

[image: number 4 count 0]

[image: number 4 count 4]

And since I love [Biml](http://www.bimlscript.com/)

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
<!-- 
EPT should be ON when 
record count is non zero
or run number is 1

It should be OFF when
record count is zero
and run number is not 1 
-->
        <Package Name="SO_62518244">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="runnumber" DataType="Int32">0</Variable>
                <Variable Name="record_count" DataType="Int32">0</Variable>
                <Variable Name="EnableEPTRuleRunNumber" DataType="Boolean" EvaluateAsExpression="true">@[User::runnumber]==1</Variable>
                <Variable Name="EnableEPTRuleRecordCount" DataType="Boolean" EvaluateAsExpression="true">@[User::record_count]==0</Variable>
                <Variable Name="EnableEPT" DataType="Boolean" EvaluateAsExpression="true">@[User::EnableEPTRuleRunNumber] || @[User::EnableEPTRuleRecordCount]</Variable>
                <Variable Name="LabelRunNumber" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true">"RunNumber " + (DT_WSTR, 5) @[User::runnumber] + " rule is " + (DT_WSTR, 10) @[User::EnableEPTRuleRunNumber]</Variable>
                <Variable Name="LabelRecordCount" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true">"RecordCount " + (DT_WSTR, 5) @[User::record_count] + " rule is " + (DT_WSTR, 10) @[User::EnableEPTRuleRecordCount]</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Container Name="Before"/>
                <Container Name="EPT Placeholder">
                    <Expressions>
                        <Expression ExternalProperty="Disable">!@[User::EnableEPT]</Expression>
                    </Expressions>
                    <PrecedenceConstraints>
                        <Inputs>
                            <Input OutputPathName="Before.Output" />
                        </Inputs>
                    </PrecedenceConstraints>
                </Container>
                <Container Name="After">
                    <PrecedenceConstraints>
                        <Inputs>
                            <Input OutputPathName="EPT Placeholder.Output" />
                        </Inputs>
                    </PrecedenceConstraints>
                </Container>
                <Container Name="Debug RecordCount">
                    <Expressions>
                        <Expression PropertyName="Name">@[User::LabelRecordCount]</Expression>
                    </Expressions>
                </Container>
                <Container Name="Debug RunNumber">
                    <Expressions>
                        <Expression PropertyName="Name">@[User::LabelRunNumber]</Expression>
                    </Expressions>
                </Container>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

The names of the tasks don't always update until you close and re-open the package as they don't get the pulse to re-evaulate themselves as the variables change but it does work.

Comment: Loved your solution! Especially the BIML part. Learned a lot from it. However, upon reading your post I ralised there is only one scenario in which the task is executed so I did use the disabled property and set it as : @[User::runnumber]!=1 &&  @[User::record_count]!=0